# Magento event for adding order comment

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1.9, orders, event-observer, history

Can anyone please let me know if there is any magento event available for adding comment to a particular order?
Let me know if question is not clear.

Answer (score 5):

So firstly you have to think about what a comment is. In the case of the order a comment is simply a field on the table `sales_flat_order_status_history`. So a comment itself cannot be track so easily. What I would suggest is that you look into the before and after save events for this model.

1. `sales_order_status_history_save_before`,
2. `sales_order_status_history_save_after`

What you can do with these events, as you will have the history object is then check to see if the comment attribute is null or not and then do what you wanted.

If the comment is not null then this can be treated as the saving of a comment on an order.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following event in config.xml

```
<events>
      <sales_order_place_after>
        <observers>
          <someeventname>
              <type>singleton</type>
              <class>modulename/observer</class>
              <method>ordercomment</method>
          </someeventname>
        </observers>
      </sales_order_place_after>
    </events>


public function ordercomment($observer)
{
    $_order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $_order->addStatusToHistory($_order->getStatus(),'some messagge',false);
    $_order->save();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but i need an event which is solely run for adding comment to order. will it (sales_order_place_after) work even we add comment to an order which is already placed?

Comment: @SANKU. Hi how to send sms automatically after place an order in magento-1.9.1.1 like mail.

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58453/how-can-i-send-a-sms-upon-successfull-check-out-in-magento/58454#58454