# How can i send a sms upon successfull check out in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

How can i send a sms upon successful check out in magento , as i have a third party

sms api integrated already with another project , how can i give all the module as

a library or any other workaround for this in magento ?

Comment: can you show your sms api code?

Comment: that is not in magento though ? so you want to see how i am sending the sms api url ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Icecreamsandwich,you can do this by [magento event observer](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method).There are lot of event on order place

**Just:**

1. `checkout_submit_all_after`
2. `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`
3. `sales_order_place_after`

etc

### Observer code:

```
<?php
class MyNameSpace_MyModule_Model_Observer
{
public function orderSms(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $incrementId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getIncrementId();
    $custName = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getCustomerFirstname();
    $orderPrice = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getGrandTotal();
    $orderId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getId();
    $order= $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()
    $mobile =  trim($order->getShippingAddress()->getData('telephone'));
    /* write your Sms code */

}
}
```

You can use any one of this but depends on conditions.

### Using sales_order_place_after event;

config.xml code is like:

```
<events>
    <sales_order_place_after>
    <observers>
        <amit_sms>
        <class>mymodule_model_prefix/observer</class>
        <method>orderSms</method>
        <type>singleton</type>
        </amit_sms>
    </observers>
    </sales_order_place_after>
</events>
```

Comment: Actually am a newbie in magento , where to put the observer code first ? In app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Block\Sucess.php ?

Comment: Can you explain this in details pls

Comment: okay i done it as checkout_onepage_controller_success_action observer it works properly , whether it will work same for the sales_order_place_after observer too ? because i need to send sms only after placing the order .

Comment: Good .. @lcecreamsandwish

Comment: Teja.do know about  event observer

Answer (score 1):

1) For sending SMS on the successful checkout use following observer event.

```
<checkout_onepage_controller_success_action></checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
```

in your sms module's config.xml.you need to create a module for this

```
<global>
    <events>
        <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
            <observers>
                <send_sms_on_order_success>
                    <type>singleton</type> 
                    <class>Yourpackage_SMS_Model_Observer</class> 
                    <method>order_success</method> 
                </send_sms_on_order_success>
            </observers>
        </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
    </events>
</global>
```

and in your module's observer.php file

```
class Yourpacakage_SMS_Model_Observer {
        public function order_success($observer){

            // sms code goes here

        }
}
```